# Universal Windows 8.1 App Page Change

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1-universal

I am trying to change pages when a text block is selected but I don't know how to get my app to go to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer to my question. In order to navigate between pages, you need to make the following call when the event you want the transition to happens:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(/*name of page you want to transition to*/));
```